# Import and make use of Polymer-Dart 1.0.0 release candidate

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I do love Polymer - and I do love Dart. And the Polymer-Dart library was pretty much the best thing ever happend to Web development (imho).

Polymer 1.0 has been released a while ago and Googlers are working hard to build the corresponding Dart wrapper as stated in Dart's Web Development Google Group.

I've built a fairly huge project quite a while ago in Polymer 0.5 and it's time to upgrade. Due to various changes in Polymer 1.0 the migration is quite hard and a lot of code breaks are expected. Since Polymer 1.0 is meant to build the final API structure for future releases, I decided to start from scratch and build the project in Polymer 1.0. Right now, there is no official 0.17 Polymer-Dart wrapper released, which is why I want to make use of the developement branch '0.17-0-dev-interop-reverse'.

However, right now, I am wondering, how to actually import the Polymer-Dart dev project into my Polymer Dart project.
I am using Webstorm 10 and Dart 1.11.3.

Also, what is currently not supported by the development version? I read somewhere that it's missing a transformer - is that still the case?

**My question is basically, how to use Polymer 1.0 in Dart already without waiting for the official 0.17 release.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the following `pubspec.yaml` it works fine for me:

**Dart Polymer 1.0.0-rc.2**

```yml
name: todomvc
description: TodoMVC built with the polymer.dart package
version: 0.15.1
dependencies:
  browser: any
  polymer: 1.0.0-rc.2
  polymer_elements: 1.0.0-rc.2
  reflectable: 0.3.2
  web_components: ^0.12.0

transformers:
- web_components:
    entry_points:
    - web/index.html
    - test/listorder_test.html
    - test/markdone_test.html
    - test/mainpage_test.html
- reflectable:
    entry_points:
    - web/index.dart
    - test/listorder_test.dart
    - test/markdone_test.dart
    - test/mainpage_test.dart
- test/pub_serve:
    $include: test/**_test{.*,}.dart
- $dart2js:
    minify: true

environment:
  sdk: ">=1.2.0 <2.0.0"
```

There is an [TodoMVC application](https://github.com/dart-lang/sample-todomvc-polymer) ported to Polymer.dart 0.17 (see the branches `polymer-0.17` and `polymer-0.17-behaviors`.

Comment: The UnimplementedError is expected today when running through pub on the polymer-0.17-behaviors branch. This is the primary reason an actual release of polymer-0.17 hasn't already been sent out. I am working actively with the reflectable team to get everything we need implemented, but its a work in progress.

You can start a normal server though (not pub serve/build) and open your app in dartium, and everything should work fine.

Comment: Apart from changing polymer_interop ref from 0.2.0-rc1 to 0.2.0-dev, this works for me as well.

Comment: An example project with my settings https://github.com/bwu-dart-contributing/polymer_elements/tree/demo2/demo

Comment: Amazing, the first time I tried it polymer_interop ref: 0.2.0-rc1 wasn't able to be found, but 0.2.0-dev was.  Now it does find rc1.  Who can tell what went wrong there.  So the above works perfectly fine.  Thanks

Comment: Didn't work for me. "Host key verification failed." Git clone didn't work. :(

Comment: I guess this is Windows. AFAIR there was an issue recently with ssh.

Comment: Well, if anyone has an issue on Windows, I may have fixed it by cloning polymer-dart and polymer-interop using the Github for Windows app, which bypasses SSH issues. Then I changed the pubspecs to use path dependencies instead of git dependencies.

Comment: I did not express myself well! In fact I want to know if to use Polymer Dart 1.0 (release candidate) can be made in the latest stable version 1.12.1 SDK (or I need to consider dev version 1.13)?

Comment: I'm not aware of any features Polymer uses that were not already available in 1.12.1. I expect it to work. I'm pretty sure Polymer will make use of the new mixin features as soon as they are implemented, but they are not yet in dev nor bleeding edge but are about to be added.

Comment: I updated my answer for the published (hosted) `polymer`, `reflectable`, and `polymer_elements` versions.