# pub serve output error that it "Cannot handle private identifier"

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have the following file race.dart

### race.dart

// Copyright (c) 2015

```
@export
@jsonObject
@ValidIf( _isRaceValid, customDescription: '$invalidStr Race' )
class Race extends Object
    with JsProxy, Exportable {
  @export
  @jsonProperty
  @reflectable
  @ValidIf( isRequiredNounValid, customDescription: 'invalid noun' )
  @NotEmpty( )
  @Length( min: 2 )
  String race = '';

  @export
  @jsonProperty
  @reflectable
  @ValidIf( isOptionalNounValid, customDescription: 'Invalid nound' )
  String ethnicGroup = '';

  @export
  @jsonProperty
  bool isValid = false;
}

bool _isRaceValid( Race r ) {
  if (( r.race.length >= 2 ) &&
      (r.ethnicGroup.isEmpty )) {
    return r.isValid = true;
  }
  else {
    return r.isValid = false;
  }
}
```

### pubspec.yaml

```
name: epimss_polymer_reg
description: A starting point for Dart libraries or applications.
version: 0.0.1
author: zoong <zonga@gmail.com>
#homepage: https://www.example.com

environment:
  sdk: '>=1.8.3 <2.0.0'

dependencies:
  #async_commands: ^0.2.5
  bwu_fontawesome_iconset_svg: ^0.3.0-1
  drails_validator: ^0.0.1
  exportable: ^0.1.0
  jsonx: ^2.0.1
  polymer_elements: ^1.0.0-rc.1
  polymer: ^1.0.0-rc.2
  reflectable: ^0.3.1
  validator: ^0.0.4
  web_components: ^0.12.0

dependency_overrides:
  drails_commons: '0.0.6'
  logging: '0.11.2'

dev_dependencies:
  test: ^0.12.0
```

When I attempt to run my application (index.html) the follow error is displayed by pub serve

```
Cannot handle private identifier _isRaceValid
[Error from Reflectable on epimss_polymer_app|ReflectableTransformed]:
```

I see that reflectable 0.3.3 that I am using give some info about private identifiers at https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/reflectable

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

### EDIT 1

I did as you suggested Gunter. Now I see on hint of errors in the DartAnalysis or any where. But the application now runs, displays a blank page and shows no output errors.

My index.dart is

```
import 'package:bwu_fontawesome_iconset_svg/bwu_fontawesome_iconset_svg.dart';

import 'package:epimss_polymer_app/main_app.dart';
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

/// [MainApp] used!
main() async {
  await initPolymer();
}
```

When I run the application with debug I get the following:

> Observatory listening at http://127.0.0.1:63906/
>           Internal error: 'http://localhost:63342/epimss_polymer_app/web/index.dart': error: line 40 pos 2016: expression is not a valid compile-time constant
>           final _data = {const prefix0.JsProxyReflectable(): new r.ReflectorData([new r.ClassMirrorImpl(r"PolymerMixin", r"polymer.src.common.polymer_js_proxy.PolymerMixin", 519, 0, const prefix0.JsProxyReflectable(), const [], const [], const [], -1, {}, {}, const {}, -1, 0, const [], const [prefix0.jsProxyReflectable]), new r.ClassMirrorImpl(r"JsProxy", r"polymer.lib.src.common.js_proxy.JsProxy", 519, 1, const prefix0.JsProxyReflectable(), const [], const [], const [], -1, {}, {}, const {}, -1, 1, const [], const [prefix0.jsProxyReflectable]), new r.ClassMirrorImpl(r"dart.dom.html.HtmlElement with polymer.src.common.polymer_js_proxy.PolymerMixin", r"polymer.lib.polymer_micro.dart.dom.html.HtmlElement with polymer.src.common.polymer_js_proxy.PolymerMixin", 583, 2, const prefix0.JsProxyReflectable(), const [], const [173, 174, 175], const [], -1, const {}, const {}, const {}, -1, 0, const [], const []), new r.ClassMirrorImpl(r"PolymerSerialize", r"polymer.src.common.polymer_serialize.PolymerSerialize", 519, 3, const prefix0.JsProxyReflectable(), const [176, 177], const [176, 177], const [], -1, {}, {}, const {}, -1, 3, const [0], const []), new r.ClassMirrorImpl(r"dart.core.Object with polymer.lib.src.common.js_proxy.JsProxy", r"epimss_polymer_shared.data.dart.core.Object with polymer.lib.src.common.js_proxy.JsProxy", 583, 4, const prefix0.JsProxyReflectable(), const [], const [], const [], -1, const {}, const {}, const {}, -1, 1, const [], const []), new r.ClassMirrorImpl(r"ClinicalFeature", r"epimss_polymer_shared.data.ClinicalFeature", 7, 5, const prefix0.JsProxyReflectable(), const [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], const [178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191], const [], 1, {}, {}, {}, -1, 5, const [], const [prefix12.jsonObject, const prefix13.ValidIf(prefix4.isClinicalFeatureValid, customDescription: 'ClinicalFeature $invalidStr')]), new r.ClassMirrorImpl(r"WebOptions",

... a whole lot more of similar output (over 140,000) characters.

What does this all means?

### EDIT 2 - pubspec.yaml

```
name: epimss_polymer_app
version: 0.0.1
description: A web app built using polymer.dart.
author: 
#homepage: https://www.example.com

environment:
  sdk: '>=1.9.0 <2.0.0'

dependencies:
  browser: ^0.10.0
  bwu_fontawesome_iconset_svg: ^0.3.0-1
  epimss_polymer_reg:
    path: J:/workspace/epimss/dart/epimss_polymer_reg
  epimss_polymer_shared:
    path: J:/workspace/epimss/dart/epimss_polymer_shared
  epimss_shared_core:
    path: J:/workspace/epimss/dart/epimss_shared_core
  polymer_elements: ^1.0.0-rc.1
  polymer: ^1.0.0-rc.2
  reflectable: ^0.3.1
  web_components: ^0.12.0

dependency_overrides:
  drails_commons: '0.0.6'
  logging: '0.11.2'

dev_dependencies:
  test: ^0.12.5

transformers:
- web_components:
    entry_points: web/index.html
- reflectable:
    entry_points: web/index.dart
- $dart2js:
    $include: '**/*.bootstrap.initialize.dart'
    minify: true
    commandLineOptions:
    - --trust-type-annotations
    - --trust-primitives
- test/pub_serve:
    $include: test/**_test{.*,}.dart
```

Comment: At first glance your `pubspec.yaml` is missing the transformer configuration. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/32243217/217408 for an example. Register html entry point files (`index.html`) with the `web_components` and Dart entry point files (`index.dart`) with the `reflectable` transformer. If this isn't the issue please publish a minimal example project to GitHub that allows to reproduce the problem.

Comment: The transformers are registered all right. The application was running before I attempted to add the models. I will eliminate some of the annotations on the models to see if those are the problems first. Are the following identical | Race extends Object with JsProxy, Exportable | and |Race extends JsProxy with Exportable|?

Comment: If the models use transformers you might need to change the order of the transformers in `pubspec.yaml` (don't know which one first and last though but order matters)

Comment: No transformers are used by the models, please see my pubspec.yaml above

Comment: The reason for the errors above is due to the $invalidStr variable in the statement |@ValidIf( _isRaceValid, customDescription: '$invalidStr Race' )|. $invalidStr is actually imported from another project. This works fine in pre-1.0.0rc-1 polymer. Is this issue also cause by the @reflectable? Removing this causing the errors to disappear entirely. I would like to know what the possibilities are.

Comment: The `ValidIf` annotation doesn't seem to be related to Polymer. I have no idea what it is supposed to do or where it comes from.

Comment: You are right. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dart:mirrors` and reflectable can't access private members.
To fix it you need to make `_isRaceValid` public.